# What's the R.H.S. of divergence theorem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In $$\int_{\Omega} F \cdot D \phi \space dx = - \int_{\Omega} \text{div} F \phi \space dx$$ formulation of Divergence Theorem, is the R.H.S. $$(\text{div} F) \cdot \phi$$ or $$\text{div}(F \cdot \theta)$$?

---

My lecture notes give:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the boundary term here altogether. You should have
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} \phi\vec F\cdot\vec n\,dS = \int_\Omega \text{div}(\phi\vec F)\,dV = \int_\Omega \phi\,\text{div}(\vec F)\,dV + \int_\Omega \overrightarrow{\nabla \phi}\cdot\vec F\,dV.$$
The right-hand side is obtained by using the product rule.

Comment: But what I've written is what my lecture notes give.

Comment: Perhaps they have written such that the boundary term is equal to zero.

Comment: $\phi$ is a function with zero boundary data, so the boundary term is zero.

Comment: The OP was edited after my response. There were no hypotheses of compact support in the initial post :)